# Bootstrap 4 forms Button location

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hey i have a problem with my button location on my site

```
 <form id="filter_view" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label for="select_id">option</label>
        <select id="select_id" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label for="inputZip">write</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-1 align-bottom">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary align-bottom">submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

resulting in this site:
[Website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmrOt.png)

but i want the submit button in the row of my input-box, any ideas?

Comment: you can use a blank lable  <label ></label> http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/315/

Comment: sadly not working

Comment: it is working just increase the view window size

Comment: where do i have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "form-inline" class inside form tag and add label without text in last form group.

```css
.form-inline .form-control {
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
}

.form-inline .btn {
margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <form class="form-inline">
    <label for="select_id">option</label>
        <select id="select_id" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
        <label for="inputZip">write</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary align-bottom">submit</button>
  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BrotCast, answer updated with your html, no need to add extra css, bootstrap default class can handle this.

Comment: i tried form-inline already :), on my side it is now mixed together

(button over textfield)

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and align the button to the bottom of the column.

View fullscreen to see or visit this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jaeRzo)

```css
.flex-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <label for="inputState">option</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <label for="inputZip">write</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-1 flex-bottom ">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary ">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```